# Structuring CMake Project with Multiple Toolchain Files

Tags: cmake, embedded, cross-compiling

I have a CMake question for anyone who uses CMake to cross compile for multiple targets.

How do you structure your project, including Toolchain files so that:

1. CMake compiler detection works
2. Custom toolchain specific compiler flags make it to the final build?

This is confusing to me because sometimes the required flags to build the final binary will not work for the compiler checking phase, so if you set the variable `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` in the Toolchain file, the detection step fails.
If decided to use the convention of setting `CROSS_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` in the Toolchain file, and then use that variable in the main CMakeLists.txt. I’d love it could be hidden in the Toolchain file, so I can build for different targets and not have any extraneous details in the main CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I don't know much about toolchain files, but I thought toolchain files were supposed to be used _in place_ of compiler detection. Am I missing something?

Comment: "the required flags to build the final binary will not work for the compiler checking phase" - What kind of flags do you mean? If you are about an ldscript, then yes, its specification is not a part of toolchain file. Note also that you may disable the compiler checking, either completely or partially (e.g. without checking linkage). Please, provide details of your **concrete** problem. In the current form the question is too vague for being answered.

Comment: >Note also that you may disable the compiler checking, either completely or partially (e.g. without checking linkage). 

I have done this, although I like leaving it enabled.

> Please, provide details of your concrete problem.

There isn't a concrete problem now. I am looking for "best practices", or various techniques and styles for organizing projects that compile for multiple targets